# MySQL How to enable load local data server/client side (with Powershell)

Tags: mysql, powershell

I'm trying to upload a CSV file into MySQL using a PowerShell script. I'm working on a Windows 10 machine and using MySQL 8.0. Every time I run the script from a PowerShell console, I get the following error:

> Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Loading local data is disabled; this must be enabled on both the client and server sides"

The PowerShell script is as follows:

```powershell
[system.reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")
$mysqlConn = New-Object -TypeName MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
$mysqlConn.ConnectionString = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=sql_store;UID=root;PWD=password"
$mysqlConn.Open()
$MysqlQuery = New-Object -TypeName MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
$MysqlQuery.Connection = $mysqlConn
$MysqlQuery.CommandText = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\Mau\\Desktop\\test_01.csv' INTO TABLE sql_store.store_list FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (campo1, campo2, campo3);"
$MysqlQuery.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I have added the option `OPT_LOCAL_INFILE=1` in Edit_Connection -> Advanced and the `LOAD DATA` command works fine if executed in the workbench.

But, when I try to run the same SQL command using PowerShell, it returns the above error. I've tried to set `local_infile=` in file my.ini but it doesn't work or maybe I've set it in the wrong place.

Could you please explain me how to enable `LOAD DATA` on both the server and client sides? what are the options I have to set in the my.ini file to make the PowerShell script run?